# Standard practice for showing a location in IOS - mapkit or link to google map?

Tags: iphone, ios, google-maps, mapkit

I have an app that I want to have a button that will show you the location of somewhere (it's a conference app, so want to show the convention centre on google map). At the moment my link opens up google maps with the long/lat.

My question is, is that standard practice in IOS? or it against some design guideline (seeing as it opens another app). Should I embed a mapkit view instead? I'm under a really tight deadline so don't want to get my app rejected, so thought I'd ask which was the generally accepted practice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither will get your app rejected but using an embedded map will make your users happier. You might also give a button which opens the location in the maps app so the user can get directions.